# IBM Bluemix IotFoundation : Receiving messages from non-declared devices

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot

I'm using the IBM Bluemix Iot Foundation (IoTF fot shortness).

On one hand, I use a NodeJs application, declared in the API keys of IoTF. This application posts messages as a device :

`const IotfApp = require("ibmiotf").IotfApplication;
    const appClient = new IotfApp(configApp);
    /* ... Stuff */
    appClient.publishDeviceEvent(deviceType, deviceId, "metrics", "json", msg);`

So far, so good.

I have declared two (out of tens) devices for test purpose in the IoTF.

On the other end, I use a NodeRed IoTF boilerplate sample. Everything seems to work, BUT i receive messages from device that HAS NOT been declared in the IoTF.

Is this a normal behaviour ?
How can I list (nothing found using API) all the terminals sending messages but not 'officially' declared ?

Thanks.

--- Edit ---

Screenshots :

Iot Foundation : https://i.stack.imgur.com/frBLj.png

NodeRed boilerplate : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUsDl.png

Comment: What do you mean by "declared devices for test purposes"?  Are all 10 devices registered as part of the org?

Comment: Do the devices have a .cfg file that has their org and credentials stored?  If so, then when they start they are publishing info to the Watson IoT  Platform (formerly known as IoT Foundation).

Comment: No. Only two devices are part of the org. They do not have a .cfg, as they do not publish directly to the platform. Only the nodejs app publishes messages on theur behalf.

Comment: Screenshots added to the main post to illustrate what is happening

Comment: It looks like perhaps someone did register the F86E5 device.  If you can send me your org then I can check what devices are registered.

Comment: It may be a good idea to open a  ticket to Bluemix support so we can investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

If the device that is showing up in Node Red debug (F86E5) was previously registered as a device in Watson IoT (IoTF) and then deleted, the data will still be streamed until you have restarted the connection on that device.

If a device connects and authenticates then begins to send data before it is  deleted, the Watson IoT platform does not disconnect it.   However, when it tries to reconnect the registration will be checked at that point and it will no longer be able to send data to that org.